# Cin recibe una orden sin haber realizado ningún input

Tags: c++, csv

Tengo un pequeño menu que pide al usuario una accion y dependiendo de esta ejecuta una de las opciones. Tras cualquiera de las opciones se realiza la pregunta de nuevo:

```
while(final==1){
cout << "\n\nOrden:";

getline (std::cin,eleccion);
transform(eleccion.begin(), eleccion.end(), eleccion.begin(), ::tolower);

if (eleccion == "ayuda"){               
    ...
    }   

else if (eleccion == "fichero"){
    ...
    }                               

else if (eleccion == "usuario"){
    string idnum;
    cout << "\nIntroduzca el ID del usuario:";
    cin >> idnum;
    int viajes;
    viajes = usuarioFun(idnum, direccion);
    cout << "\nEl/la usuario/a " << idnum << " ha realidado " << viajes << " viajes.\n";
}                       

else if (eleccion == "fin"){
    final = 0;                      
    }

else{
    ...
    }                                   

}
```

Pero tras la orden de *"Usuario"* se escribe en eleccion o este tiene un valor que hace que se salte el `cin` de entrada de datos, este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La funcion a la que llama *Usuario* ya ha sido comprobada y ni modifica el valor ni hace que se ejecute algo distinto.
¿Alguna idea de porque el `cin` recibe un valor cuando no se ha dado ninguno?

Comment: El problema es que `cin >> variable` consume caracteres de `cin` hasta encontrar un retorno de carro, pero _no consume el retorno de carro_. Por otro lado, `getline()` lee todo lo que haya en `cin` hasta el primer retorno de carro, inclusive (es leído, pero no se retorna como parte del resultado). En la segunda iteración del bucle `getline()` se encuentra al principio del buffer de entrada el retorno de carro que el último `cin >> variable`  había dejado sin leer, por eso retorna la cadena vacía. ¿No puedes hacer `cin >> eleccion` en lugar de usar `getline()`?

Comment: Tienes toda la razon, no me habia dado cuenta hasta que lo has mencionado y en efecto, al cambiar `getline` por el `cin >> eleccion` se ha solucionado completamente! Muchas gracias ^^